# Notepad++ "Replace in Files" with complex folder filter

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace, everything

I'm trying to replace something in all `.js` files that have a folder called `Views` somewhere in their pathname. This includes these samples:

- C:\Project1\Web\Views\Entity\List.js
- D:\Project2\Views\AnotherFolder\YetAnotherFolder\Go.js

Is that possible in Notepad++?

Can voidtools Everything be used with Notepad++? I mean to search in a given list of files that can be found using voidtools Everything?

Comment: That's not a job for Notepad++, you'd better write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: Can voidtools everything be used with NotePad++? I mean to search in a given list of files that can be found using voidtools everything?

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Welcome to Super User!</sup>

While this cannot be done with Notepad++ itself, you can combine it with *voidtools Everything* application.

First, close all tabs in Notepad++

In Everything, enable options "Menu → Search → Match Path" and "Menu → Search → Enable Regex".

And type that in search bar:

```
\\views\\.*\.js$
```

Review all files and make sure it's what you want, since this action cannot be undone!

Now select all files with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, and drag them into Notepad++ window.

Then open search-and-replace dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>), go to "Replace" tab, carefully set the replacement options and hit "Replace in all open documents".

Now review your changes in files, save all files with "Menu → Save All" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and close all tabs with "Menu → Close All" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>)